# Getting Variables inside Javascript Function using BeautifulSoup, Python, Regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, lxml

There is an array `images` defined within a Javascript function that needs to be extracted and converted from the string into a Python list object.

Python's `Beautifulsoup` is being used to do the parsing.

```
        var images = [
            {   
                src: "http://example.com/bar/001.jpg",  
                title: "FooBar One" 
            },  
            {   
                src: "http://example.com/bar/002.jpg",  
                title: "FooBar Two" 
            },  
        ]
        ;
```

**Question:** Why is my code below unable to capture this `images` array, and how can we fix it?

Thank you!

**Desired Output**
A Python list object.

```
[
    {   
        src: "http://example.com/bar/001.jpg",  
        title: "FooBar One" 
    },  
    {   
        src: "http://example.com/bar/002.jpg",  
        title: "FooBar Two" 
    },  
]
```

**Actual Code**

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Example of a HTML source code containing `images` array
html = '''
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var images = [
            {   
                src: "http://example.com/bar/001.jpg",  
                title: "FooBar One" 
            },  
            {   
                src: "http://example.com/bar/002.jpg",  
                title: "FooBar Two" 
            },  
        ]
        ;
        var other_data = [{"name": "Tom", "type": "cat"}, {"name": "Jerry", "type": "dog"}];

</script>
<body>
<p>Some content</p>
</body>
</head>
</html>
'''

pattern = re.compile('var images = (.*?);')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
scripts = soup.find_all('script')  # successfully captures the <script> element
for script in scripts:
    data = pattern.match(str(script.string))  # NOT extracting the array!!
    if data:
        print('Found:', data.groups()[0])     # NOT being printed
```

Comment: Are you looking to end up with something like `{ src: "http://example.com/bar/001.jpg", title: "FooBar One" }`?

Comment: @JackFleeting Sorry I did not mention the desired output. Updated the question. I am looking for the entire array including the `[` & `]` so that I can convert it into a Python list object.

Answer (score 2):

### Method 1

Maybe,

```
 \bvar\s+images\s*=\s*(\[[^\]]*\])
```

might work to some extent:

#### Test

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Example of a HTML source code containing `images` array
html = '''
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var images = [
            {   
                src: "http://example.com/bar/001.jpg",  
                title: "FooBar One" 
            },  
            {   
                src: "http://example.com/bar/002.jpg",  
                title: "FooBar Two" 
            },  
        ]
        ;
        var other_data = [{"name": "Tom", "type": "cat"}, {"name": "Jerry", "type": "dog"}];

</script>
<body>
<p>Some content</p>
</body>
</head>
</html>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
scripts = soup.find_all('script')  # successfully captures the <script> element

for script in scripts:
    data = re.findall(
        r'\bvar\s+images\s*=\s*(\[[^\]]*\])', script.string, re.DOTALL)
    print(data[0])
```

#### Output

> [
>               {
>                   src: "http://example.com/bar/001.jpg",
>                   title: "FooBar One" 
>               },
>               {
>                   src: "http://example.com/bar/002.jpg",
>                   title: "FooBar Two" 
>               },
>           ]

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Jbuc9o/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/Jbuc9o/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

### Method 2

Another option would be:

```
import re

string = '''
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var images = [
            {   
                src: "http://example.com/bar/001.jpg",  
                title: "FooBar One" 
            },  
            {   
                src: "http://example.com/bar/002.jpg",  
                title: "FooBar Two" 
            },  
        ]
        ;
        var other_data = [{"name": "Tom", "type": "cat"}, {"name": "Jerry", "type": "dog"}];

</script>
<body>
<p>Some content</p>
</body>
</head>
</html>
'''

expression = r'src:\s*"([^"]*)"\s*,\s*title:\s*"([^"]*)"'

matches = re.findall(expression, string, re.DOTALL)

output = []
for match in matches:
    output.append(dict({"src": match[0], "title": match[1]}))

print(output)
```

#### Output

```
[{'src': 'http://example.com/bar/001.jpg', 'title': 'FooBar One'}, {'src': 'http://example.com/bar/002.jpg', 'title': 'FooBar Two'}]
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jbuc9o/1/)

Answer (score 1):

*re.match*  matches from the beginning of the string. Your regex has to pass the entire string. Use

```
pattern = re.compile('.*var images = (.*?);.*', re.DOTALL)
```

The string is still not in a valid python list format. You have to do some manipulations before you can apply `ast.literal_eval`

```
for script in scripts:
    data = pattern.match(str(script.string))
    if data:
        list_str = data.groups()[0]
        # Remove last comma
        last_comma_index = list_str.rfind(',')
        list_str = list_str[:last_comma_index] + list_str[last_comma_index+1:]
        # Modify src to 'src' and title to 'title'
        list_str = re.sub(r'\s([a-z]+):', r'"\1":', list_str)
        # Strip
        list_str = list_str.strip()
        final_list = ast.literal_eval(list_str.strip())
        print(final_list)
```

Output

```
[{'src': 'http://example.com/bar/001.jpg', 'title': 'FooBar One'}, {'src': 'http://example.com/bar/002.jpg', 'title': 'FooBar Two'}]
```

Comment: Great, your solution matches the string representation of the `images` array! However, when I tried `ast.literal_eval(data.groups()[0])` to convert it to a Python list object, I get the error `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`.

Comment: `json.loads(data.groups()[0])` gave the error `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to get there, no regex, not even beautifulsoup - just plain Python string manipulation - in 4 easy steps :)

```
step_1 = html.split('var images = [')
step_2 = " ".join(step_1[1].split())
step_3 = step_2.split('] ; var other_data = ')
step_4= step_3[0].replace('}, {','}xxx{').split('xxx')
print(step_4)
```

Output:

```
['{ src: "http://example.com/bar/001.jpg", title: "FooBar One" }',
 '{ src: "http://example.com/bar/002.jpg", title: "FooBar Two" }, ']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a shorter lazy regex and `hjson` library to deal with unquoted keys

```
import re, hjson

html = '''
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var images = [
            {   
                src: "http://example.com/bar/001.jpg",  
                title: "FooBar One" 
            },  
            {   
                src: "http://example.com/bar/002.jpg",  
                title: "FooBar Two" 
            },  
        ]
        ;
        var other_data = [{"name": "Tom", "type": "cat"}, {"name": "Jerry", "type": "dog"}];

</script>
'''
p = re.compile(r'var images = (.*?);', re.DOTALL)
data = hjson.loads(p.findall(html)[0])
print(data)
```